# Typescript: Computed dynamic object property is not typed

Tags: typescript

I have this typescript code:

```
export type Mutation = (state: State, data: unknown) => void

export type Mutations = {
  [key: string]: Mutation
}
```

```
private buildMutations(): Mutations {
    return {
        ['3']: (state, data) => {},
        ['' + 3]: (state, data) => {},
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5VP2m).

In `['3']: (state, data) => {}` state & data are typed, but in `[''+3]: (state, data) => {}`, state & data are not typed, why? How do i fix it?

Comment: I have `state: State` and `data: unknown` in both `'3'` and `'' + 3`. Couldn't reproduce.

Comment: What version of typescript do you have in that repo? Works in v5.1.6 in the typescript playground that you linked.

Answer (score 0):

It was an IDE issue, i have some Vue files in my repo which made Webstorm use Volar as the Typescript service, using the regular Typescript service fixed the issue